# TabLayout.Tab not filled

Tags: android, android-layout, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I'm using `TabLayout` with `PageViewer` but the Tabs are not filling the whole TabLayout.

In xml, setting `GRAVITY_FILL` and `MODE_FIXED` was not enough, but setting

```
android.support.design:tabMaxWidth=0dp
```

will fix the problem.

However, since  `TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(ViewPager)` would override `TabLayout`'s `TabItem`s, so I'm setting up Tabs programmatically.

Now the TabLayout.Tab are not evenly displayed.... Can anyone help?

**TabLayout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_selected_text_color"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"> <!--this makes tabitem text filled evenly-->
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/fragment_list_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/tab_layout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager> <!--not overlapping with appbar-->


    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:elevation="@dimen/shadow"
        android:tint="@android:color/background_light"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_input_add"
        tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute"
        tools:targetApi="lollipop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**MyActivity.java**

```
 ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.fragment_list_pager);
        FragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new ReminderFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new MyOnPageChangeListener()); 
        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager,true);//needs to be called before addTab, overrides TabTitle


        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        for(int i =0; i<titles.length; i++){
            View tabCustomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab_title_layout,null);
            tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setCustomView(tabCustomView), i);

            tabLayout.setTabMode(TabLayout.MODE_FIXED);
            tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
        }

    }
```

gradle:

```
compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0"
```

currently:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WpH4Y.png)

**Update**
This issue happened earlier today and I googled so much but didn't have it fixed. 
Until just now...

**Changes are:**

1. add TabItem in TabLayout(even though according to official website
   they are merely place holders) and not really added;
2. use `Tab t = TabLayout.getTab;` `t.setCustomView(v);`

so in TabLayout.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    app:tabGravity="fill"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/tab_selected_text_color"
    app:tabMode="fixed"
    app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"> <!--this makes tabitem text filled evenly-->

    <!--TabItem are just view holders and not actually added to TabLayout-->
    <!--overridden by viewPagerAdapter.getPageTitle()-->
    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabItemList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_color_selector"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabItem
        android:id="@+id/tabItemMap"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_color_selector" />
</android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>
```

**in MyActivity.java**

```
 Tab tab = tabLayout.getTabAt(i);
 tab.setCustomView(tabCustomView);
```

This fixes things for me. Thanks y'all!!

Comment: I think you need to put the entire xml in tablayout in a LinearLayout with orientation vertical

Comment: So I think you've solved the problem already. What's your question then?

Comment: @ReazMurshed the problem was not solved. With the above code, the tabs are not filled....

Comment: `android.support.design:tabMaxWidth=0dp` you said your problem is fixed after setting this.

Comment: @VinayJaju done

Comment: @ReazMurshed it was. but TabLayout.setupWithViewPager(ViewPager) would override anything defined in xml